# In Firebase Analytics, what's the difference between event parameters and custom dimensions?

Tags: firebase-analytics, custom-dimensions

When creating a login event, as in

`Analytics.logEvent(RSMCheckList001Helpful, parameters: ["response":"yes", "card": cardText1])`

...it's easy to see how parameters are used.

However, Firebase Analytics also provides adding Custom Dimensions, configurable in the web interface, which it then suggests you use as parameters on an event.

Is there an advantage to using Custom Dimensions, as opposed to simply adding parameters? I'm not sure what they're for, or how to use them.

Answer (score -1):

The custom dimensions use the parameters that you add on Events.

When you add a custom dimension with Event scope you can see that dimension on the Events details that have the parameter added on the Custom dimension.

I understood it like this..